# Map from Object[] to CustomObject. Using findBySQL query

Tags: java, sql, java-8, mapping, java-stream

Having a simple SQL Table like:

```
NOTIFICATION (ID, NAME, NOTIF_DATE, ...)
```

---

I am excecuting a SQL query from my back-end app using code like:

```
this.findBySQL(MY_SQL_QUERY, params...);
```

---

The SQL SELECT QUERY is excecuted correctly and returns the rows expected. The problem i am facing is that the returned rows are wrapped to ***Object[]***, but after this query, i want to filter the results using ***Java 8 stream and filter functionality***.

I want the results to be mapped to my custom Object Notification, which look like:

`Notification { long id, String name, Date notif_date, ... }`

I could create my own mapper, getting the result values from the ***Object*** i get from the query, example:

```
Notification not = new Notification();
not.setName(obj[1]);
...
```

But i think that this approach is not a good implementation beacause it depends on the order of the columns returned, and i have to code for every attribute to be setted.

Is there any way of mapping from this ***Object[]*** to my ***Notification***?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the poor code but I have no better approach for this issue.

Comment: Well, you should know the order of the returned columns, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Column-order dependence, if it is present, is a characteristic of your `findBySQL()` method.  If you cannot reliably predict the order and meaning of elements of the `Object[]` you receive from it, then you've already lost when you receive the data in that form.  If you *can* predict the column order, then I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: Yes, i can predict the order, but i still need to set every attribute of my Noitification.

Answer (score 2):

It’s easiest if your `Notification` class has a constructor that accepts the fields from the database (or you can add such a constructor):

```
    List<Object[]> rows = this.findBySQL(MY_SQL_QUERY, params);
    List<Notification> notifs = rows.stream()
            .map(r -> new Notification((Long) r[0], (String) r[1], (Date) r[2]))
            .filter(n -> n.getName().startsWith("m"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You haven’t told us the exact return type of `findBySQL()`, so I am guessing a bit. I hope you will be able to tailor the code to your exact situation.

I put in a fairly meaningless `filter()` in the stream just for the sake of the example. I would find it more convenient to filter after you have created the `Notification` objects. You can also filter before if you prefer. I didn’t really understand why you didn’t do your filtering in SQL.

If you cannot add a good constructor for the purpose, it’s a bit longer, but really not very much more complicated:

```
    List<Notification> notifs = rows.stream()
            .map(r -> {
                Notification notif = new Notification();
                notif.setId((Long) r[0]);
                notif.setName((String) r[1]);
                notif.setNotif_date((Date) r[2]);
                return notif;
            })
            .filter(n -> n.getName().startsWith("m"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: You could call `filter(r -> ((String) r[1]).startsWith("m"))` first, before creating the `Notification` objects. This way, you would create less objects, reducing overhead (depending on how many results you expect).